# adding a fade toggle effect into animation jquery

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a button that when clicked rotates the button and slidetoggles a paragraph.  I'd like to add a opacity animation toggle effect, so when the button is clicked it rotates and also toggles between an opacity of .3 adn .65 but I'm not 100 percent sure what the best way is to do it.  I don't have access to jqueryUI unfortunately just jquery, so animating the toggle class doesn't seem to be an option.  I was thinking maybe fadetoggle but that fades the element all the way out and back in, maybe there's a way to modify that?  effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO is what I'm trying to toggle between the opacities.

```
var effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO = document.getElementById('effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO');
effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO.style.setProperty("-webkit-transition", "-webkit-transform 0.25s ease-in-out");

var effects_of_yoga_2010_DEG = 0;

$("#effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO").click(function() {
$("p#effects_of_yoga_2010_TEXT").slideToggle("250");
effects_of_yoga_2010_DEG += 45;
effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO.style.setProperty('-webkit-transform', 'rotateZ('+effects_of_yoga_2010_DEG+'deg)');   
});
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe fadeTo will help you out

http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/

```
  $('.element').click(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo('slow', 0.5, function() {
      // Animation complete.
    });
  });
```

I took that from the jquery page. This will fade the element to an opacity that you define, you would need to define when to fadeTo what

```
  $('.element').click(function() {
    // check to see if it is open
    if($(this).hasClass('open')) {
       // item already opened

    } else {
       // item is closed
    }

  });
```

Comment: so how does that get setup as a toggle?

Comment: this cannot toggle, that's why I said you have to define when to fadeTo what. The toggle fade will fade in/out the element comletely as you have already found out. it's not hard though with jquery you can add a class when the item is open and remove class when it is closed, so when clicked check if class is on the element so you know which state you are in. updated my answer, hope it helps

Comment: yea you can also use the other answer using toggle and define both states. He uses animate which works too, fadeTo is just packaged animate

Comment: would the class just be empty?

Comment: @loriensleafs I am not sure what you mean by that question. You don't need to add class attribute in the html if that's what you are asking. You also don't need to define any styles for the class if you don't want to. What I do usually is - defining some styles for no open class and then some styles for with open class, this all depends on design and behavior

Answer (score 1):

This might do it

```
$("#effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO").toggle(function() {
  $("p#effects_of_yoga_2010_TEXT").slideToggle("250");
  effects_of_yoga_2010_DEG += 45;
  effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO.style.setProperty('-webkit-transform', 'rotateZ('+effects_of_yoga_2010_DEG+'deg)'); 
  $("#effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO").animate({
    opacity: 0.3
  }, 250); 
}, function() {
  $("p#effects_of_yoga_2010_TEXT").slideToggle("250");
  effects_of_yoga_2010_DEG += 45;
  effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO.style.setProperty('-webkit-transform', 'rotateZ('+effects_of_yoga_2010_DEG+'deg)');  
  $("#effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO").animate({
    opacity: 0.65
  }, 250); 
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: that mostly works, it's strange though, I have the button set to an opacity of .3 on load, and then when you click it using that function it fades it out further, and then back up, so it's almost like it's startign otu at .3, fading lower then .3 adn then coming back up another amount? I'm not really sure, here's the fiddle I'm doign all of this on  http://jsfiddle.net/loriensleafs/TMGv3/18/

Comment: Oh good, glad I could help. I also came up with a solution that should cover them all as opposed to each individually. Its in here for your reference: http://jsfiddle.net/TMGv3/20/